# MaskEdit For Android Delphi 10.3 CE

Tags: android, delphi, edit, sample, masking

I am trying to make an Edit text like this: "9999 9999 9999 9999" when the user is typing. But I didn’t find any MaskEdit in my Edit control.

Can anyone help me? Can you give me some sample code for my Edit?

Comment: FireMonkey doesn’t have any MaskEdit functionality, like VCL does.

Comment: Any Solution, how to make maskedit at android???

Comment: you would have to handle keystroke events manually, inserting spaces when needed, or at least parsing the whole text and reformat it on each key press.